# Linked list not working for input

Tags: c++

I'm writing code that takes integers that are input from the user and creates a linked list and then prints out the list. However, when I enter values 1,2,3,4,5, the output is only 5 5 5 5 5

Please tell me where am i wrong here.

The code is as follows:

```
include"iostream"
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int number;
    node* next;
};

int main()
{
    node* head;
    head = NULL;
    int i,n,x;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>x;
        //Insert(x);
        node* temp;
        temp = new node;
        temp->number = x;
        temp->next = NULL;
        head = temp;
    }
    //Print();
    node* temp;
    temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
            cout<<temp->number<<" ";
            temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your insert logic is wrong. You change what `head` points to, but you don't "link" the old head. You also are using very C-like syntax and are not taking advantage of C++'s `class`.

Answer (score 1):

**This looks a bit wrong:**

```
while(temp != NULL)
{
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        cout<<temp->number<<" "; // Only this is part of the for() loop
        temp = temp->next; // This happens after the for() loop ends
}
```

Only the first line gets executed by the `for()` loop so it keeps outputting the same number. Why is the for loop there anyway? What is it supposed to do?

**Try this:**

```
while(temp != NULL)
{
    cout<<temp->number<<" ";
    temp = temp->next;
}
```

See if that works better.

**ALSO:**

As @crashmstr pointed out your insert logic is wrong:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>x;
    //Insert(x);
    node* temp;
    temp = new node;
    temp->number = x;
    temp->next = NULL; // this should point to the nextnode
    head = temp;
}
```

**Try:**

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>x;
    //Insert(x);
    node* temp;
    temp = new node;
    temp->number = x;
    temp->next = head; // the current begining
    head = temp;
}
```

***ALSO 2:**

```
include"iostream" // not right
```

Please use:

```
#include <iostream> // correct!
```

Comment: That will then just output a single `5`, since the insert logic is wrong (but definitely *is* a correction to the output code).

Comment: Changing `head` makes it point to what is supposed to be the last node in the list. Printing it out gives `5 4 3 2 1`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Indeed. I am trying to keep it simple and don't feel the need to do all the work for him, just point out some errors.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that when setting the `head` pointer, you should only do so when the list is empty (i.e when `head == NULL`). We should do this after we create the new node so we know what to set `head` to:

```
node* temp = new node;
temp->number = x;
temp->next = NULL;

if (head == NULL) // if the list is empty then...
    head = temp;  // temp is the start of the list
```

There's also another problem. `temp` is supposed to be added to the *end* of the list each time it's created. If the list is empty then `head` is the end of the list, but if the list already has elements then we need to go to the end and set the `next` pointer of that node to `temp`. This is fairly straightforward, all it takes is a while loop to iterate over the list to the end:

```
if (head == NULL)
    head = temp;
else // the list is not empty
{
    // so we need to go to the end
    node* p = head;
    while (p->next != NULL)
        p = p->next; // keep going through

    // p now points to the last node
    p->next = temp;
}
```

There's also the option of keeping a `prev` node that points to the last element inserted. This makes it so that we don't have to go through the list each time to find the end:

```
node* head = NULL, prev = NULL;

for (/* ... */)
{
    // ...
    if (head == NULL)
        head = prev = temp;
    else
    {
        prev->next = temp;
        prev = temp;
    }
}
```

The last thing is the way you're printing. You shouldn't have a nested for loop here:

```
while (temp != NULL)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        cout << temp->number << " ";
        temp = temp->next;
}
```

Taking it out will make it print correctly.